# Vault not adding new key

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am trying to use api to add new key to a path, say secret/sub path.  In that path I already have two keys values, I want to add one more, the following is my api

```
curl --request POST --data '{"bar": "baz"}' http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/sub/cha3
```

The result was it didn't append this new key under secret/sub path, instead it created another new path named 'sub' under secret/secrets!

Any idea how to do add a new key?  Guess I want to append  new key to existing path.

My vault version is 1.0.3

Answer (score 0):

```
curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request POST \
    --data '{"bar": "baz"}' \
    https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/sub
```

If you want to add more data to the same path, you will need to specify the old params (otherwise it will override it):

```
curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request POST \
    --data '{"bar": "baz", "foo": "fee"}' \
    https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/secret/data/sub
```

See the [documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/kv/kv-v2.html#create-update-secret) for more details